# Eclipse starts (the process only) but the program doesn't open after installing theme

Tags: eclipse

I have this problem that's quite annoying. Once I installed eclipse it worked fine. After installing darkest dark theme via the eclipse market and restarting eclipse the splash screen pops up and the process starts as observed in the task manager.

[image]

However after a few seconds, the splash screen above disappears and nothing happens after that no matter how long I wait. In the task manager this however is always visible.

[image]

If I click on the eclipse icon again I get this message:

[image]

If i end the task and click on the icon the process repeats; splash followed by nothing.

Does anyone know why this occurs after installing themes and how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry to hear you're running into this, can't say we've seen something like this before. When you end the task, can you confirm that [workspace_location]/.metadata/.lock is deleted. If not, can you delete it and try again (just in case this is a one-off glitch). 

1) Any additional eclipse processes running, if you examine the Task Manager?
2) I'm assuming this is Windows 10, but the dialog has a trim that we're not familiar with. Any different settings / UI configurations?
3) Were you being prompted to choose the workspace on startup, or did you have a default workspace set?

Comment: Hi! The LOCK file does not get deleted when I terminate the task. Once I manually delete the LOCK file and start eclipse again, the same thing happens and a new LOCK file is created. 1) No other eclipse processes running. 2) This is a windows 10 64-bit operating system, with a customized theme. 3) Yes, only first time after installing the theme.

Comment: 1) Can you tell us what custom Windows theme this is, wondering if that's the issue - can you disable it and try?
2) Any log files in your Eclipse installation's configuration folder?
3) What if you say "yes" to the workspace question and choose a new dummy workspace, does that start?
4) What base Eclipse distribution is this (Java, C Development, etc.) Did you have any additional plugins installed? Can you give us a listing of the files/folders in the Eclipse installation's features directory?

Comment: Ok this is weird. I re-installed eclipse after a clean uninstall and the installed the theme. Once prompted to also install the DevStyle Icon, i did not check that box. Now it works. I changed nothing else except that this time I opted not to install the DevStyle Icon. I hope this can help someone else having the same problem in the future.

Comment: Glad you managed to keep moving. When you say, "DevStyle Icon", I assume you're talking about the "DevStyle Icon Designer". We've tested this quite extensively with 2019-06 (and I retested it explicitly today) and it worked fine.

Can you share any details on the customized theme that you have installed - perhaps that's what caused the issues, and we'd love to replicate and fix. Also, do let us know if you had any additional plugins installed beyond the vanilla Eclipse distribution. Thanks!

Comment: The theme I used was exactly this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=flcFkqzBAPo. I followed it step by step.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, we're going to take a look!